# Aligning two equations (one split and another non-split)

Tags: equations, latex3, eqnarray

I have the below two equations,

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{split}
C_{N+1} &= h\left( X_{N+1}; \hat{\phi}_{N+1} \right)  + \left[ h\left( X_{N+1}; \phi_{N+1} \right) - h\left( X_{N+1}; \hat{\phi}_{N+1} \right)  \right] \\ 
& + u^{g}_{N+1} + u^{r}_{N+1}
\end{split}
\end{eqnarray}
\begin{eqnarray}
C_{N+1} &= h\left( X_{N+1}; \hat{\phi}_{N+1} \right)  + u^{\phi}_{N+1}  + u^{g}_{N+1} + u^{r}_{N+1}
\end{eqnarray}
```

which gets displayed as below:

[image]

How could I align both these equations at the = sign ?

What I intend to do is :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't really want to align the + sign with the = sign.

You can use `split`, but ***don't*** ever use `eqnarray`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
C_{N+1} &= h( X_{N+1}; \hat{\phi}_{N+1} )  + [ h( X_{N+1}; \phi_{N+1} ) - h( X_{N+1}; \hat{\phi}_{N+1} ) ] \\    
        &\qquad + u^{g}_{N+1} + u^{r}_{N+1}
\end{split}
\\[1ex]
C_{N+1} &= h( X_{N+1}; \hat{\phi}_{N+1} )  + u^{\phi}_{N+1}  + u^{g}_{N+1} + u^{r}_{N+1}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I removed all `\left` and `\right` commands and you can see that the formulas have become *more* readable.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The align package works without the eqnarray package!
Solution as follows:

```
\begin{align}
C_{N+1} &= h\left( X_{N+1}; \hat{\phi}_{N+1} \right)  + \left[ h\left( X_{N+1}; \phi_{N+1} \right) - h\left( X_{N+1}; \hat{\phi}_{N+1} \right)  \right] \nonumber \\
& + u^{g}_{N+1} + u^{r}_{N+1} \\
C_{N+1} &= h\left( X_{N+1}; \hat{\phi}_{N+1} \right)  + u^{\phi}_{N+1}  + u^{g}_{N+1} + u^{r}_{N+1}
\end{align}
```

[image]

Comment: It is also common to use `&\phantom{=}`